# Slick Slider showing unrequired images in Custom Post Type Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, slick.js

Hi I am Struggling in Slick Slider. I have given the following code  and i am getting some different image src along with the image src  i want

**This is my page-aboutus.php**

```
<div class = "aboutus-ourworks" id = "wrapper">
<?php 
    $loop = new WP_Query( 
    array( 'post_type' => 'latest_work_feature', 'order' => 'ASC'));
            while( $loop->have_posts() ) :$loop->the_post(); 
                if ( have_posts() ):
                    $imagess = get_field('latest_work_image');
                    $title = the_title();
                    ?>

                <?php foreach ($imagess as $image1) : ?>

                    <img src = "<?php echo $image1; ?>" alt="">

                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

**This is in my script.js**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.aboutus-ourworks').slick({
            arrows: false,
          speed: 700,
         // autoplay:false,
});
    });
```

In The console i  get this numerous img unrequired src

[Front End Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ55w.png)

Comment: Looks to me that `$image1` is an array. It's creating a new slider for every element in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment - **it Looks to me that $image1 is an array. It's creating a new slider for every element in the array.**

I'm going to make the assumption that you're using ACF. If this is the case you will need to specify the key. In your case - `<img src = "<?php echo $image1['url']; ?>" alt="">`

Comment: Thank you.. it helped.... i removed the foeach  and renamed the variable and added['url''] that did the job...